# Exception for detokenize

Tags: detokenize

following problem:

```
\openin\inputfile=#1%
\loop%
    \read\inputfile to \readline%
    \unless\ifeof\inputfile%
        \global\edef\filecontent{\filecontent\readline^^J}%
\repeat%
\closein\inputfile%

.....

\immediate\write\targetfile{\filecontent}
```

The input files contain special characters like "#", "$" and so on, as well as LaTex commands. I need to expand the LaTex commands on file read, all other special character should remain unchanged.

What I need is something like a

```
\detokenize{\catcode`\\=0 \readline}
```

which assigns all tokens except "\" a catcode of 12. Any ideas?

Comment: why use detokenize at all? just set the special characters to catcode 12 (eg `\let\do\@makeother \dospecials` would be enough) then set `\\ ` back with `\catcode\`\\=0`

Comment: Change the name `\readline` into something else, because `\readline` is a primitive.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're trying to write out a copy of some file, but with commands fully expanded.

You can do away with `catchfile`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.in}
\foo{abc} #$% \foo{A}%
xx\foo{#}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{--#1--}

\newcommand{\setupexpandfile}{%
  \endlinechar=`^^J % when writing out, newlines will be preserved
  \catcode`\#=12 % so # makes no problem
  \catcode`\%=12 % so % is not a comment
  % maybe others
}

\newcommand{\expandfile}[2]{%
  \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{#1}{\setupexpandfile}%
  \immediate\openout\denisout=#2\relax
  \immediate\write\denisout{\temp}%
  \immediate\closeout\denisout
}

\newwrite\denisout

\expandfile{\jobname.in}{\jobname.out}

\stop
```

I don't think you really need other characters to be managed specially.

Here is the contents of the `.out` file after processing.

```
--abc-- #$% --A--%
xx--#--
```